# Why should I configure any tracking library in the AppDelegate?

Tags: iphone, ios, google-analytics, appdelegate, adobe-analytics

This is a very specific question.

Its not very clear to me why do we initialize or configure the external libraries such as Google-Analytics or Adobe-Omniture, in the

```
didFinishLaunching
```

method of the AppDelegate?

If the library is configured outside the AppDelegate - Lets say in another VC - will not the Tracking work?

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to initialize any analytics on didFinishLaunching,
because you want it to be ready whenever you call it, like a logger.

You may initialize it from any other component, but make sure you do it first thing (so no other component would call it when it's not ready), and only once, to avoid bad state.